# Using openXML in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, openxml

I'm trying to use the `openXML` function with SQL Server 2012 for the first time and I'm running into an issue. If I have a node that has no value i.e

```
<amenity id="bathtub" name="Bathtub" />
```

I'm always getting a NULL value returned when using the code below to extract the data from the XML. Any normal element ie

```
<name>Attic Loft in a historical building</name>
```

seems to work fine. Is there an easy way of checking for the existence of a node using openXML?

```
DECLARE @XML AS XML, @hDoc AS INT, @SQL NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @XML = XMLData FROM myXML

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML

SELECT *
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'properties/property/amenities')
WITH 
(
name [nvarchar](250) '../name',
externalId [nvarchar](50) '../id',
externalURL [nvarchar](250) '../landing_page_url',
description [nvarchar](max) '../description',
bathtub [bit] 'bathtub '
)

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc
GO
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use the built-in, **native XQuery support** for SQL Server - `OpenXML` is old, clunky, leaks memory and so forth....

You can access **attributes** with the XPath expression using a `@` indicator - something like this:

```
DECLARE @input XML = '<amenity id="bathtub" name="Bathtub" />'

SELECT
    ID = @input.value('(/amenity/@id)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    Name = @input.value('(/amenity/@name)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
```

Based on your XML input, you have two attributes - `id` and `name` (and nothing called `bathtub` as you seem to access in your OpenXML example....)

```
<amenity id="bathtub" name="Bathtub" />
         ^^           ^^^^
         *            * 
         *            * --> attribute is called "name"
         *
         *--> attribute is called "id" (not "bathtub" - that's it's *value*, not the name!)
```

For more information on XQuery support in SQL Server 2005 - read those articles:

- [Introduction to XQuery in SQL Server 2005](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345122%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)
- [An Overview of XML Support in SQL Server 2005](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_data/article.php/c19491/SQL-Server-2005-XQuery-and-XMLDML--Part-1.htm)

**Update:** if you want to iterate over a list of XML elements, use the `.nodes()` function with a XPath expression to get a list of XML fragments which you can then grab individual bits from - something like this:

```
DECLARE @input XML = '<properties><property><amenity id="bathtub" name="Bathtub" /></property><property><amenity id="pool" name="Big honking pool" /></property></properties>'

SELECT
    ID = XCol.value('(amenity/@id)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    Name = XCol.value('(amenity/@name)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
FROM
    @input.nodes('/properties/property') AS XTbl(XCol)
```

Comment: agreed : OPENXML is old-school.  "Move on up"!

Comment: Damm, I thougth I was close. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Hi Marc, Can I use xquery to loop over a xml document and output the results like I was doing with openXML? I'm not great at SQL but I think your example would only give me row 1 of my document

Comment: @JamesPrivett: sure! Use the `.nodes()` function with an XPath expression to get a list of XML fragments which you can then "shred" into their individual pieces. Read the links I've posted in my response to get a feel for how to do that. Updated my response with a sample